# ODBC DSN for a Named Instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from a C++ application as per my previous question: [C++ ODBC SQL Server 2008 Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530080/c-odbc-sql-server-2008-connection)

My DSN in C++ is

```
SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(local)\DB1;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;PWD=password;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
```

So my DSN is actually

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(local)\DB1;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;PWD=password;
```

This just does not work. I can connect to servers that haven't used named instances, but on my home machine I have separate instances I need to connect to.

What would be the correct DSN to use with this to connect to a SQL Sever 2008 R2 Named Instance on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC DSN for a named pipe needs to be like this

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=np:(local)\DB1;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;PWD=password;
```

With the addition on `np:` to specific that this is a named pipe rather than a `tcp:` connection.